# Is there a way to remove results from find in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory with backups.  One backup file is created each day. I need to remove these files as they fill up disk space over time.  I want to remove all files older than 5 days, BUT I need to keep a minimum of 5 files in the directory.  This is in case the backup utility fails 5 days in a row.  I currently have it just deleting anything older than 5 days.  But, that could be very concerning considering the scenario I just described.

I want to:

1. Run a find on a directory sorted by file created date
2. Remove the 5 most recent lines (files)
3. Run rm on the files that are left from the find command

I can do this in Python or a multitude of ways, but would prefer to keep it simple with a bash script.

Is there a way to do this in bash?  I was thinking of maybe piping it to a file then removing the lines that way.  Don't know if that is smarter.

Comment: If you can do this in python, totally go that way.

Comment: fair enough haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use python.

If you **KNOW** there are no filenames with embedded spaces, newlines, or other naughty bits, you could do something like this:

```
stat -c "%W %n" * | sort -rn | head -5 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm
```

---

Edit/upgrade, per KamilKuk, with thanks! Nulls FTW!

```
stat --printf="%W\t%n\0" * | sort -z -rn | head -z -n -5 | cut -z -f2- | xargs -0 rm
```

---

...but you don't, because people will find a way to do something stupid sooner or later and botch up your filesystem, so don't do that.

As an exercise, here's one way to do it in a bash script:

```
declare -A lst=()                          # create empty associative array
for f in *                                 # for each file
do ts=$( stat -c "%W" "$f" )               # get the creation timestamp
   lst[$ts]="$f"                           # use timestamp as key, name as value
done
last=( $(                                  # create simple array with subshell output
   printf "%s\n" ${!lst[@]} |              # print single column of timestamp keys
      sort -rn              |              # reverse numerical sort
      head -5                              # take the most recent 5
) )
for ts in "${last[@]}"; do rm "./${lst[$ts]}"; done # delete 5 most recent files
```

See why you might want to use python? :)

Comment: This does not verify that entries are plain files, by the way. . .

Comment: `xargs rm` will interpret quotes too - I recommend use `xargs -d'\n'` _always_ (when it's available - it's not POSIX) . The `stat --printf="%W\t%n\0" * | sort -z -rn | head -z -n -5 | cut -z -f2- | xargs -0 echo rm`  will handle any bytes in filenames (no need to use python :p )

Comment: thanks!  I will be going with Python haha.  But, I appreciate seeing it in bash.